# What are the dimensions of a cylinder inscribed in a right circular cone of height 4 and base radius 6 with maximum volume?

Tags: calculus

I'm a student in Calculus class, and my teacher assigned us the following problem:

> A cylinder is inscribed in a right circular cone of height $4$ and radius (at the base) equal to $6$. What are the dimensions of such a cylinder which has maximum volume?

The problem is I'm currently out of town, and the teacher is out of office. I've scoured my calculus book trying to find a similar problem to try and find a place to begin on this one, but I can't seem to find ANYTHING like it (a recurring issue in this class). I have a feeling it is an optimization problem but I honestly don't understand the question (how do you make a cylinder from a cone?).

Where do I even start with this problem? I feel that once I get a clearer understanding of what the question is asking, I'll be able to answer it on my own.

Comment: @Moo, I see they have the answer there, but I still don't even understand the question. What is meant by "cylinder inscribed in a right circular cone"? How do you create a cylinder from a cone?

Comment: "Inscribed in" means the cylinder just barely fits inside the cone.

Comment: I think you are having trouble visualising this. Think of a can of beans standing upright. Then place a paper cone directly over the can so that the intersection is the circle at the top of the can. Sometimes it's better to start with the cylinder and put the cone round it!

Comment: @DavidK, fantastic! This question makes much more sense now (definitely an optimization problem). Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @ScottBurns, that's a good way of putting it. I had a bit of trouble understanding what was meant by "inscribed", but now I see that it means "barely fit inside of", rather than "drawn/written on"

Comment: You seem to have problem in making a cylinder from a cone. Instead of trying with pen try with  knife: take a cone of ice cream with top  flat. Or cheese or butter might be better.  Play around with knife  to cut and make   a cylinder. There will be lots of such geometry problems in calculus. So play with knife and scissors before studying further. Or else you will get stuck like this. Fortunately even if you are out of town without your textbook or professor,  you can buy ice-cream/butter  anywhere in the world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a (not-to-scale and I-totally-didn't-misread-the-question-at-first-as-6-being-the-diameter-instead-of-the-radius) picture of the cone and cylinder in question (behold my abysmal drawing skills in Microsoft Paint thanks to my expired license on Mathematica!)

[image]

In any case, we can let the radius of the inscribed cylinder be $x$. That must therefore mean that the height of the cylinder is $4 - \frac{4}{6}x$. This makes the volume of the cylinder

$$V = \pi x^2 \left(4 - \frac{2}{3} x\right) = \pi \left(4x^2 - \frac{2}{3} x^3\right)$$

To find the maximum volume of the cylinder we take the derivative of $V$ with respect to $x$ and set it to $0$:

$$\frac{dV}{dx} = \pi \left(8x - 2x^2\right) = 0 \Rightarrow 8x - 2x^2 = 2x(4-x) = 0$$

$x = 0$ leads to a trivial case, which leaves us with $x = 4$. This means that the height is $4 - \frac{2}{3} \cdot 4 = \frac{4}{3}$, and the volume is therefore $$V = \pi \cdot 4^2 \cdot \frac{4}{3} = \frac{64}{3}\pi$$

Comment: The radius is 6 i didnt get why you have written 3

Comment: Oh! My apologies, I thought $6$ was the diameter. Let me correct that. (Do I really have to redraw that though...)

Comment: No if you just edit the maths I think I can understand it

Comment: I blame the 3-4-5 triangle for making me assume 6 was the diameter xD it's nicer when the hypotenuse is an integer! In any case, the corrections have been made, hope it helps!